# Scrapy - is it possible to extract Payload Request from Response

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

is it possible to extract and set as variable the "Payload Request" which has been pushed in order to receive particular response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the request object in the callback function by `response.request`.
This object is the request object itself, so it contains everything you passed in the request. It doesn't have a "payload" attribute though.

The equivalent should be `response.request.body`, assuming you had a body in the request. Everything else is still there, headers, cookies, meta, method, etc

More on the params of request [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).

Comment: Thank you for the info, do you know why when I'm trying to access and change a part of the payload request I'm getting "TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Are you trying to change the payload of a request after the request was executed? It's hard to answer this with such little context, consider open a new question and include the code you are running that's causing the error.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to change the payload and paginate the page. I made a new question with the code included here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511301/load-a-series-of-payload-requests-and-perform-pagination-for-each-one-of-them