# Load a series of payload requests and perform pagination for each one of them

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

Hi I'm trying to send a series of payload requests and for each one of them to perform a pagination. To achieve this for each one of the "payload request" a variable "offset" should be incremented. Unfortunatelly the code outputs the following error "TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json


class KauflandBasicProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'kaufland_basic_products'
allowed_domains = ['www.shopme.io']

custom_settings = {'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'groceries.pipelines.BasicProducts': 365}}


categories = [
                "8d7a9abf-b90b-4c07-9e18-ed2283dfd71f",
                "24ddb04a-f9b9-44f8-b78d-00ef5cd79977",
                "3502a7bd-7459-4a51-91df-17375b15e03e"
]

def start_requests(self):
    for category_id in self.categories:
        payload = {"category_id": category_id}  
    
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='www.shopme.io/v1/feed',
        )

def parse(self, response):
    payload_var = response.request.body
    # offset_var = int(payload_var['offset'])

    resp = json.loads(response.body)
    # print(resp)
    products = resp.get('feed').get('items')[0].get('items')
    # # print(products)
    for product in products:
        
        yield{
            'product' : product.get('name'),
            'price' : product.get('price'),
            'price_promo' : 'n/a', 
            'weight' : 'n/a',
            'weight_text' : 'n/a',
            # 'brand' : product.get('brand').get('name'), 
            'country_of_origin' : 'n/a',
            'source' : product.get('vendor_name'),
            'link' : product.get('image_url')
            # 'current_page' : response.meta['current_page']
            # 'user-agent' : response.get('User-Agent').decode('utf-8')
        }

        count_available_products = resp.get('feed').get('count')
# increment_number = len(resp.get('feed').get('items')[0].get('items'))

# if current_payload['offset'] <= count_available_products:
#     current_payload['offset'] += increment_number
    
        if count_available_products >= 12:
            # offset_var += 12
            offset_var = response.meta['offset'] 
            offset_var += 12
            payload_var['offset'] = offset_var
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://disco.deliveryhero.io/verticals/api/v1/feed",
                method="POST",
                body=json.dumps(payload_var),
                headers={
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that when you retrieve the request body you have a bytes object, not a dictionary. That's why you get a `TypeError` exception.

```
payload_var = response.request.body # This is a bytes object
...
payload_var['offset'] = offset_var  # This raises an exception
```

The solution is using `json.loads()` method to convert it back into a dict.

```
payload_var = json.loads(response.request.body)
```

---

There were other options for you to avoid this error, using `payload` as a class variable (just like `categories`) is one of them.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution! Do you have any idea how can I stop the spider from execution when there is no more products. I tried it by adding "if len(products) == 0:
            raise CloseSpider('Reached last page...')" but it seems like the spider is already in infinity loop.